# Calculate the area of a solid of revolution

Tags: volume, area, solid-geometry, centroid

So the subject title is self-descriptive. My question is how can I calculate the area of a solid of revolution with the information below:

```
• Cross section area (the cross section is a closed polygon without holes)
• Volume of revolution
• Volume Centroid coordinates
```

Take for example a rectangle revolved around the "x" axis which form a ring once is revolved. Data for the example:

```
• Cross section (rectangle):  368.97
• Volume of revolution: 1313668.59513298                    
• Volume Centroid coordinates: (921.45, 1.36117994286124e-13, -2.26863323810207e-14)
```

Any examples are welcomed.

Comment: Do a Google search for the theorem of Pappus.

Comment: The first theorem of Pappus states that the surface area S of a surface of revolution generated by the revolution of a curve about an external axis is equal to the product of the arc length s of the generating curve and the distance d traveled by the curve's geometric centroid x. The problem is that I do not know the arc length. The second theorem relates to the cross area however I am looking for the surface of revolution. So I do not see  how the theorems could be applied to my problem.